# How do I improve dwellers' happiness?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have a capped and maxed stat vault. All dwellers are level 50 and maxed at 10 for all stats across the board.
My current objective is getting everyone to a solid 100% happiness. But this isn't working for me. Many dwellers are at the 76% to 96% and not going any higher.
Dwellers are in the right rooms according to the green corners and the quest credits.
They are also in correct maxed +4 gear for that stat associated with the room.
Any ideas or suggestions? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Putting dwellers in rooms they are proficient in will only raise happiness to 75%.  It works if they are low, but otherwise doesn't help you in your current situation.

There are only two ways to raise it past 75%:

- Successfully complete a rush, +10%
- Make a baby, +50%

The rush is a risk because failing is an automatic -10%, on top of the damage if it drops their HP too low.  If you want to use rush to raise happiness to 100%, make sure the failure rate is close to 0%.

Making a baby, although gives you a huge bonus, is ALSO a risk.  Suddenly having a huge amount of babies being born will tax your food and water resource.  IIRC you also cannot evict a child.